What is the proper way of including examples in Python docstrings?
How to include examples for function calls in Python docstrings? See @examples tag in R documentation. Or what is the proper way to include examples?
I'm looking for something like this:
def my_func(x):
  """prints x.
  :param x: string to print
  :example: 
  my_func("hello world!")
  """

  print(x)

This is not a duplicate of How to embed code examples into a docstring? I'm not specifically asking about Sphinx, even though this may be part of the answers.

The official Python details are at https://docs.python.org/3.11/tutorial/controlflow.html#documentation-strings.

@oldboy: that link only has a short section on docstring which doesn't address the issue, does it?

So inserting a code-block:: doesn't work? You're using RST syntax for the parameters (which Sphinx, but not only Sphinx, understands). What is rendering your examples? There is no one "proper way", it depends what tools are processing the docstrings and how.

It could look something like this:
def my_func(x):
  """prints x.
  :param x: string to print

  Example:
      >>> print(my_func(x))
      True
  """
  return True


Edit:
Here is an example from fastapi.exceptions.HttpException (Wayback Machine archive):
class HTTPException(StarletteHTTPException):
    """
    An HTTP exception you can raise in your own code to show errors to the client.

    This is for client errors, invalid authentication, invalid data, etc. Not for server
    errors in your code.

    Read more about it in the
    [FastAPI docs for Handling Errors](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/).

    ## Example

    ```python
    from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException

    app = FastAPI()

    items = {"foo": "The Foo Wrestlers"}


    @app.get("/items/{item_id}")
    async def read_item(item_id: str):
        if item_id not in items:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Item not found")
        return {"item": items[item_id]}
    ```
    """

